# I want to connect Windows Server

Tags: server, windows, remote-desktop, remmina, rdesktop

I want to connect to the Windows Server. I used Remmina and Rdesktop but both of them  occur error. I think this error is about TLS. How can I solve that? please help me.
Thanks

Versions:
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Windows Server 2012 r2

RDesktop

```
Core(warning): Certificate received from server is NOT trusted by this system, an exception has been added by the user to trust this specific certificate.
Failed to initialize NLA, do you have correct Kerberos TGT initialized ?
Failed to connect, CredSSP required by server (check if server has disabled old TLS versions, if yes use -V option).
```

Remmina

```
[02:01:24:268] [100277:100303] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - rdp_client_connect:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_SECURITY_NEGO_CONNECT_FAILED [0x0002000C]
[02:01:24:268] [100277:100303] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.connection] - Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
[02:01:34:083] [100277:100318] [ERROR][com.freerdp.common.settings] - [freerdp_settings_get_bool] Invalid key index 131
[02:01:34:083] [100277:100318] [ERROR][com.freerdp.common.settings] - [freerdp_settings_get_bool] Invalid key index 0
[02:01:35:468] [100277:100318] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - transport_connect_tls:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_TLS_CONNECT_FAILED [0x00020008]
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you’re using and which version of Windows Server you’re trying to connect to? This will make it much easier to offer an accurate answer 

Comment: thanks for your comment. I did