# How can I connect to the Windows Server 2012 R2 from Remmina?

Tags: server, windows, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

I want to get access to my Windows Server 2012 R2. There are some errors when I try to connect it.

versions:
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Windows Server 2012 R2

```
remmina-Message: 21:03:03.356: Remmina does not log all output statements. Turn on more verbose output by using "G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all" as an environment variable.
More info available on the Remmina wiki at:
https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/wikis/Usage/Remmina-debugging
Load modules from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/remmina/plugins
Remmina plugin glibsecret (type=Secret) has been registered, but is not yet initialized/activated. The initialization order is 2000.
The glibsecret secret plugin has been initialized and it will be your default secret plugin

(org.remmina.Remmina:142829): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:03:03.427: g_ascii_strdown: assertion 'str != NULL' failed

(org.remmina.Remmina:142829): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:03:03.427: g_strrstr: assertion 'haystack != NULL' failed

(org.remmina.Remmina:142829): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:03:03.427: g_strrstr: assertion 'haystack != NULL' failed

(org.remmina.Remmina:142829): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:03:03.427: g_strrstr: assertion 'haystack != NULL' failed

(org.remmina.Remmina:142829): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:03:03.427: g_strrstr: assertion 'haystack != NULL' failed
Warning: Remmina is running with a secrecy plugin, but it cannot connect to a secrecy service.

(org.remmina.Remmina:142829): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:03:03.454: gtk_menu_attach_to_widget(): menu already attached to GtkMenuItem
[21:03:07:138] [142829:142842] [ERROR][com.freerdp.common.settings] - [freerdp_settings_get_bool] Invalid key index 131
[21:03:07:138] [142829:142842] [ERROR][com.freerdp.common.settings] - [freerdp_settings_get_bool] Invalid key index 0
[21:03:08:341] [142829:142842] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - transport_connect_tls:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_TLS_CONNECT_FAILED [0x00020008]
```

Comment: [Duplicate questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423446/i-want-to-connect-windows-server) are generally frowned upon here. As for the issue, you’ll need to update Windows Server 2012 to the final service pack, as the weaker encryption protocols have been deprecated in every currently maintained OS 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to connect Windows Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423446/i-want-to-connect-windows-server)